# Is there one word for a technique that improves your concentration?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, adjectives

This is the sentence:

> It *[Tratak]* has a cleansing effect on the eyes, is concentrating and energizing.

I want to correct "concentrating" and replace it with one word which means "increasing your capacity to concentrate."

I'm making a distinction between a technique that *uses* concentration and a technique that *improves* concentration.

Is there such a word, and if so, what is it?

Comment: Did you look for the "concentrative" in the dictionary? [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/concentrate?q=concentrative#concentrate__18) , e.g. Recently there have been sophisticated investigations of expert meditators from various concentrative practices such as Buddhism, Zen, meditative yoga, and Qi Gong.

Comment: In a word . . . no.

Comment: I did look in the dictionary. I'm making a distinction between a technique that uses concentration and a technique that improves concentration. Does concentrative cover both of these?

Comment: I think the word you want is "concentration-enhacing" or "concentration-improving". For example, "Caffeine is said to be a **concentration-enhancing** substance."

Comment: @EternalSubject In my opinion, concentrative techniques can imply both using the ability to be concentrated and improving this ability.

Comment: You don't concentrate with your eyes - it's a brain function.  I think you're trying to say too much at once.  If you say that your product is "revitalizing" or, even "refreshing", the renewed ability to concentrate would be implied.

Comment: @Oldbag It is a concentration technique that uses the eyes and affects the brain. It's not too much to say that it is concentration-enhancing. This is one of the significant results of practising Tratak.

Comment: ;-) Somebody (very friendly) downvoted you. BTW, why?

Comment: If you want to say that it improves concentration, then you're going about it the wrong way to use the verb "is" + adjective. What's wrong with the verb *improves*?  I don't understand this adjective fetish here and on ELL. Wasn't my downvote, BTW.

Comment: @Tim Romano Nothing wrong with the verb "improves". I can use it but I was asking because it would be useful if there was a word on it's own for the same meaning.

Answer (score 2):

**I think NOT**. The meaning of ***concentrative*** as given in the OED is:

Having the attribute of concentrating; characterized by concentration.

1822   Blackwood's Edinb. Mag. 12 218   The noblest examples of pure and concentrative imagination to be found in any author.

1829   C. Welch Wesl. Polity 197   The accumulation is the unfailing product of the concentrative tendency.

1881   M. E. Braddon Asphodel I. 72   Your nature is concentrative rather than diffuse.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions as to what I would use instead?

Comment: @EternalSubject Do you know a word in any language which means *increases your capacity to concentrate*?